# Merge two Hash Maps Android

Tags: java, android, optimization, performance, hashmap

I want to merge Two HashMaps.

I could use map1.putAll(map2); but I don't want to overwrite the key's as yes they will have conflicting keys.

So the keys in each map will be like this

```
word1     word1
word2     word2
word3     word3
```

and when I merge them I would like:

```
word1
word2
word3
word4
word5
word6
```

It can just overwrite the keys, aslong as the keys are incremental and use the first key text i.e. reads one of the pairs and extracts 'word' so each would be word1  word2.

But the other caveat I was thinking of the mobile environment and what I can do without having to put up a loading screen or even capable of.

So as a starter I suppose:

```
    HashMap<String, Object> hm1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    hm1.put("key1", "a");
    hm1.put("key2", "a");
    hm1.put("key3", "a");
    HashMap<String, Object> hm2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    hm2.put("key1", "1");
    hm2.put("key2", "2");
    hm2.put("key3", "3");

    HashMap<String, Object> newHM = new HashMap<String, Object>();      
    String keyWord = "";
    for (String  s: hm1.keySet()) {
        keyWord = s;
        break;
    }
    int count = 0;
    for (Object o : hm1.values()) {
        newHM.put(keyWord+count, o);
    }
    for (Object o : hm2.values()) {
        newHM.put(keyWord+count, o);
    }
```

But I'm wondering, how efficient is this? It looks correct, And is there a better way to do it? I don't want to use extra object's unnecessarily

Comment: String keyWord = "";
    for (String  s: hm1.keySet()) {
        keyWord = s;
        break;
    }

What is the point of this? it will always set keyWord to the first key in hm1

Comment: That is the idea, to retrieve the key from one of the already created maps, I forgot to remove the number from it though, so each key will be key11, key12, kat13. So I should fix that with a substring. Just looking into the List answer first tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your keys are incremental an basically represent a simple index, you should use a `List`.

You could try your own implementation of `List` which will also store a keyword.

```
class KeyWordedArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T>{
    private final String keyword;

    public KeyWordedArrayList(String keyword){
        this.keyword = keyword;
    }

    public String getKeyword(){
        return keyword;
    }
}
```

You can also do an implementation of Map :

```
class KeyWordedMap<T> extends HashMap<Integer, T> {
    private final String keyword;

    public KeyWordedMap(String keyword) {
        this.keyword = keyword;
    }

    public String getKeyword() {
        return keyword;
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends Integer, ? extends T> m) {
        for (Map.Entry<? extends Integer, ? extends T> entry : m.entrySet()) {
            int i = entry.getKey();
            while (this.containsKey(i)) {
                i++;
            }
            this.put(i, entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a valid point, however at some instances when I instantiate this hashmap object the key's aren't incremental so I want the hashmap object to work in both situations. ( I wouldn't call the merge method in this situation).

I could separate this out into two separate objects, but I don't think that should be my solution.

Comment: cool I get that thanks - I assume you think this is the optimal answer then? it uses the least new objects etc. Answered the question again so anyone looking at my Q can see the Answer

Comment: @Blundell, Yes I think it the best way to deal with this ;) But I maintain my idea to have a separated keyword.

Answer (score 0):

To match my example it would be:

```
@Override
public void putAll(Map<? extends String, ? extends Object> m) {
    for (Map.Entry<? extends String, ? extends Object> entry : m.entrySet()) {
        String keyWord = "";
        for (String  s: this.keySet()) {
          keyWord = s.substring(0, s.length()-1);
          break;
        }
        int i = 0;
        while (this.containsKey(i)) {
            i++;
        }
        this.put(keyWord +i, entry.getValue());
    }
}
```